# DatetimePicker not showing time selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, datetimepicker

[image: Only date appears here]

I have a popup window where is am using  Jquery's datetimepicker , below is the code

```
$('#id').datetimepicker({
      hour: dateTime.getHours(),
      minute: dateTime.getMinutes()
}).datetimepicker('show');
```

Problem is only Datepicker is available , I am not able to see the timepicker .
So i only can select the date but not time.

Please provide suggestions

Regards
Bits

Comment: I don't understand what you need, and I think that many other people can't understand your question too. Please, add a working example to the post. Read that **before** ask and your question will be solved faster: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There is no `time picker` in [`jquery-ui-datepicker`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) Which plugin are using?

Comment: The same code is working fine when i tried in iframe, as i am able to see both time-picker and date-picker, the problem is only with pop-up window

Answer (score 2):

Use **format** attribute like this:

```
$('#id').datetimepicker({
      format: 'dd-mm-yyyy h:i:s'
}).datetimepicker('show');
```

Comment: Ideally it should . as I already tried the same but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue.
The problem was that I have missed the **Jquery** reference in the code.
I only had **JqueryUI** refrence.
After addding **Jquery** refrence datetimePicker showing date as well as time panel.

Comment: I have the same issue. What do you mean by "missed the Jquery reference?"

Comment: I missed to include jquery reference into my page.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing this:

```
$(id).daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    timePicker24Hour: true,
    locale: {
        format: "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A"
    }
});
```